# How to version files specific for a release

Tags: git

Suppose I have a project with their versioned source files.
  But, each release could have a set of scripts, very specific to each.

For instance, with every release I could deliver a patch.sql script, for impacting database stuff.
That script is VERY diffrent with every release.

How can that script be versioned ?
Is there a strategy to manage such files ?

Comment: If it's specifically for database changes between versions, you might want to look at how [Rails handles migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for a starting point.

Comment: You might need a build process.  The build process can pre-process sql changes into a sql script.  But, for this question, it's hard to tell whether your looking for a git solution or an incremental sql migration story.  A sql migration upgrade process should be independent of your source control system.  Git just stores versioned files - it's not integral to your database problem.

Comment: For example, I've been part of large teams and seen many sql migration approaches but none were dependent on the choice for source control ...

Answer (score 1):

Files which are just for releasing, not for migrating, can be managed just like any other file.  Simply make whatever changes necessary to the file and commit them as normal.

Otherwise, a simple approach to migration is to have directories like `migration/v2_v3/` which contains all the patches and scripts necessary to go from version 2 to version 3.

For the specific topic of SQL migration, have a look at [Sqitch](http://sqitch.org/).  It's version control aware SQL change management, so you don't have to come up with your own SQL patch management scheme.